# Remove Selection Of bar in highchart with hover working

Tags: highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVUjI.png)

```
   function getComparisionReport(xAxis, series) {

        var chart = Highcharts.chart('comparison-report', {

            chart: {
                type: 'column',
            },

            title: {
                text: null
            },
            navigation: {
                buttonOptions: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: null
            },

            legend: {

                //  x: 90,
                // y: 45,
                labelFormatter: function () {
                    let laba = this.name.split('#')[0];
                    return laba.replace(' ', "_").split(' ')[0].replace('_', ' ');
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: xAxis,
                labels: {
                    x: -10
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
                outside: true,
                formatter: function () {
                   
                    var html = '<div>' +
                    '<p>Location count: <b>' + this.series.userOptions.storeCount + '</b></p><br/>' +
                     '<p>' + this.series.userOptions.Dates[this.point.index] + ': <b>' + this.total + '</b></p><br/>' +
                    '</div>';

                    return html;
                  
                }
            },

            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total Visitors'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        //color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray',
                        color: 'black',
                        //backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 255, 197, 0.7)',
                        position: 'absolute'
                    },
                    formatter: function () {

                        var points = this.points;
                        var max = 0;
                        var _html = '';
                        //for (var index in points) {
                        //    var currentValue = parseInt(points[index][0]) + parseInt(points[index][1]);

                        //}
                        max = this.cumulative;
                        if (max === 0) {
                            max = "0";
                            _html = "<div><span class='not-available'><br/>" + max + "</span></div>";
                        }
                        else {
                            _html = "<div class='rotateNew' style='text-orientation: mixed;writing-mode: vertical-lr;'>" + max + "</div>";
                               //_html = "<div style='text-orientation: mixed;writing-mode: vertical-lr;'>" + max + "</div>";
                           // _html = "<div style='text-orientation: upright;writing-mode: vertical-rl;'>" + max + "</div>";
                        }
                        //return "<center><span><br/>" + max + "</span></center>";
                        return _html;
                    }
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    events: {
                        click: function (event) {
                            return false
                        },

                    }
                    /*
                    events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {
                    if (this.name === 'This Week')
                        return false;
                    else
                        return true;
                }
    }
    */
                },
                series: {
                    /*
                    enableMouseTracking: false,
                    states: {
                        inactive: {
                            opacity: 1
                        }
                    },
                    */
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        formatter: function () {
                            //var mychart = $('#container').highcharts();
                            //var mytotal = 0;

                            //for (i = 0; i < mychart.series.length; i++) {
                            //    if (mychart.series[i].visible) {
                            //        mytotal += parseInt(mychart.series[i].yData[0]);
                            //    }
                            //}
                            //var pcnt = (this.y / mytotal) * 100;
                            // return '3';
                        }
                    },
                    events: {
                        legendItemClick: function () {

                            var name = this.name.split(' ')[0] + ' ' + this.name.split(' ')[1];
                            var _i = this._i;
                            Highcharts.each(this.chart.series, function (p, i) {
                                // alert(p.name.split(' ')[0] + ' ' + p.name.split(' ')[1])
                                if (name === (p.name.split(' ')[0] + ' ' + p.name.split(' ')[1]) && _i !== p._i) {
                                    (!p.visible) ? p.show() : p.hide()
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    },
                },
            },
            series: series,

            responsive: {
                rules: [{
                    condition: {
                        maxWidth: 500
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        legend: {
                            align: 'center',
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                            layout: 'horizontal'
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            labels: {
                                align: 'left',
                                x: 0,
                                y: -5
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: null
                            }
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: null
                        },
                        credits: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        });
    }
```

I need to disabled the selection on the bar see inside in image but the main case is that we don't need to disable the hover as well.

like if I use "enableMouseTracking: false" that cause the hover is also not working,

for more detail please have a look on image which I have attached thanks a lot the stack over flow community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable `allowPointSelect` option:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: false
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1br7o0aq/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.allowPointSelect